# Android UI patttern: Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking for code hints for this pattern: http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/horizontal-scrolling-page-indicators

I tried few Android libraries like https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow , but couldn't get the required layout.

Can anyone tell here that how can I achieve the required layout?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) class and [`ViewPagerIndicator`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) library

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ViewPager` see [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)